# What is the difference between these Explorer.exe Build Version Numbers?

Tags: windows-explorer

explorer.exe 6.0.2900.5577 
1,043,016
8/8/2008
11:35:38

explorer.exe 6.0.2900.5512
1,033,728
4/14/2008
5:00:00 am

---

Obviously the dates, times, and sizes are different, but can you tell me anything else? If you know, how did you know? Where did you find the details? Or what tools did you use to find the information?

Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

They are slightly different builds of Windows.  One machine probably has a hot fix installed that the other machine doesn't have.  You can match what hot fixes are listed in Add/remove Programs to see which one is missing.

You can also try combing through the MSKB to find the hotfix which is referenced by that version number, but Add/remove programs will probably be faster.

Answer (score 2):

Many KB articles include file lists with the corresponding version numbers.
You can also look here: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/969393/
(this is for Internet Explorer, not explorer.exe but major releases like service packs are all there).

So, 6.0.2900.5512 is Windows XP with the service pack 3.
build number 5577 will be one of the patches released after SP3.